# Cannot insert new record in mySQL database via php , updating is working , no errors throw

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

After creating new database and importing old from backup, I cannot insert new records , only updating already entered records.
I use procedural statement , here is current code

```
$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = ".....";
$password = "......";
$dBname = ".......";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dBname);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");


$stmt = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_cat (broj2,broj1,hide,broj4) VALUES (?,?,?,?) "); 
    
$stmt -> bind_param('ssss',$var_type,$var_level,$var_hide,$total); 

$stmt -> execute(); 
$stmt-> store_result();
```

Comment: Mysqli does not explicitly throw errors, so you have to check `$conn->error` to see what is going on. You could check the value of `$stmt->execute()` and if it returns false, then echo the `$conn->error` like so `if(!$stmt->execute()){echo $conn->error; exit();}` to see what errors you have

Comment: @Ant Mysqli throws errors. Checking manually for them is bad practice

Comment: You can't call `store_result` on `INSERT` There's no result to store

Comment: `utf8` charset is depreacted for the past 11 years. Please use `utf8mb4`

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: @Dharman while it does throw some errors, it does not halt on issues like Syntax errors. Also I have never heard of it being a bad practice of manually checking for error, could you provide some insight into that? All the example code in php's manual include manual checks after execution

Comment: @Ant The manual shows how to enable automatic error reporting. Mysqli reports automatically all errors that you would normally check manually. Manual checking is redundant and inconvenient. This post explains it well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param